# How do I use Nauty Traces?

Tags: graph-theory

I have recently learned of this package, however, I have limited computer knowledge so I don't know how to use it. I have followed the instruction and built it. Now, I ended with a folder full of executables. Would anyone give me some help on how to start using it? Is there any video tutorial or pdf?

Comment: At least give a reference.

Comment: Yes, look at the documentation: it lists all the executables and their options. Beyond that, the software *requires* some effort from the end user. It's main goal is not to be user friendly but to be efficient at what it does.